# jump to ruby symbol with emacs

Tags: ruby-mode

In a ruby project.
when point is at a ruby symbol, for example `UserCart::PromotionService.new(blah blah`
how can I jump to the definition of that class/module.

Comment: Normally, this functionality is bound to `M-.`. I have no idea if the mode you're using for editing ruby source code has that functionality and whether it's good enough to look for class definitions, but you can always try it.

Comment: I suspect that both http://ctags.sourceforge.net/ and https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags have ruby parsers.  Therefore you could index your project with one of these tools, then follow DoMiNeLa10's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer in a youtube

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l_gkh3CsbTk

Specifically as a prelude user, what I did was

```
kill emacs daemon

;; add to personal.el
(prelude-require-packages '(
  robe
))

emacs --daemon
emacs ~/repo/app/controllers/foo_controller.rb
M-x robe-start
M-x robe-mode
place cursor at contant/sumbol
M-x robe-jump-to-module
```

And sure enough, I was "teleported" to the module definition
in the rails application.

Update: As pointed in a previous comment, you can press `M-.` and save yourself typing `robe-jump-to-module`